# iOS Quaternion to Euler conversion for different states

Tags: ios, signal-processing, quaternions, sensor-fusion

I recorded two sets of quaternion signals from iOS for the following cases:

1. The phone is steady on table
2. The phone is standing steady vertically.

As expected, the quaternions are very different.

I am trying to convert the Quaternion to Euler to obtain heading or Yaw around z-axis. But when the phone is standing, for example the phone is in pocket ( and hence the second case), do I need to do anything different to obtain heading?

Or I just convert the quaternion obtained when the phone is in pocket and use the Yaw as heading?

Comment: You do know about gimbal lock, yes?

Comment: If you want direction of Z vector aka heading, than just transform vector Z(0,0,1) by current rotation. Than you can project it to floor plane to get 2d direction.

If not , please reformulate your question.

Comment: But how do I carry out the transformation? When I hold the phone in hand, the Z axis which is coming out of the phone screen is perpendicular to the ground, but when the phone is in pocket, it is the Y axis which is perpendicular to the ground. So how do I transform the Quaternions in the second case, where Y axis is perpendicular to the ground and Z axis is parallel to the ground.